# Using Pyspark to parse JSON strings for occurrences of each value in the list

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to PySpark and I am struggling to find how many occurrences of each IP address are in the following list:

```
sampleJson = [('{"user":100, "ips" : ["191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.99"]}',), ('{"user":101, "ips" : ["191.168.192.102", "191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.107"]}',), ('{"user":102, "ips" : ["191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.107"]}',), ('{"user":103, "ips" : ["191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.107", "191.168.192.101"]}',), ('{"user":104, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.102", "191.168.192.99"]}',),('{"user":105, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.96"]}',),]
```

Ideally, I need the results to look something like this:

| ip | count |
| --- | --- |
| 191.168.192.96 | 3 |
| 191.168.192.99 | 6 |
| 191.168.192.100 | 2 |
| 191.168.192.101 | 3 |
| 191.168.192.102 | 2 |
| 191.168.192.103 | 2 |
| 191.168.192.105 | 3 |
| 191.168.192.107 | 3 |

I have performed the following code below to get the results into a column with the user and another column that shows their ips but unable to now extract the counts of each ip into the desired output. Can anyone help?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import json

json_df = spark.createDataFrame(sampleJson)

sch=StructType([StructField('user', StringType(), 
False),StructField('ips',ArrayType(StringType()))])

json_df = json_df.withColumn("n",from_json(col("_1"),sch)).select("n.*").show(10,False)

|user|ips                                                                 |
|:---|-------------------------------------------------------------------:|
|100 |[191.168.192.101, 191.168.192.103, 191.168.192.96, 191.168.192.99]  |
|101 |[191.168.192.102, 191.168.192.105, 191.168.192.103, 191.168.192.107]|
|102 |[191.168.192.105, 191.168.192.101, 191.168.192.105, 191.168.192.107]|
|103 |[191.168.192.96, 191.168.192.100, 191.168.192.107, 191.168.192.101] |
|104 |[191.168.192.99, 191.168.192.99, 191.168.192.102, 191.168.192.99]   |
|105 |[191.168.192.99, 191.168.192.99, 191.168.192.100, 191.168.192.96]   |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) function to transform array elements into rows:

```
json_df = spark.createDataFrame(sampleJson)

sch=StructType([StructField('user', StringType(), 
False),StructField('ips',ArrayType(StringType()))])

json_df = json_df.withColumn("n",from_json(col("_1"),sch)).select("n.*")

json_df = json_df \
    .withColumn('ip', explode("ips")) \
    .groupby('ip') \
    .agg(count('*').alias('count'))


json_df.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I ran into the following issue when running your code: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

Comment: that is probably because you already have an action in your code e.g. `.show(10,False)`, I've updated example and included your code in it. please try again